# Como pego somente os maiores valores em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tenho esses dados em JSON

```
[
   {
      "nome":"Carlos",
      "quantidade":"25",
      "local":"Inglaterra"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Mariana",
      "quantidade":"15",
      "local":"Brasil"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Gustavo",
      "quantidade":30,
      "local":"França"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Murilo",
      "quantidade":"60",
      "local":"Belgica"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Luiz",
      "quantidade":"10",
      "local":"Brasil"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Tata",
      "quantidade":"18",
      "local":"Brasil"
   }
]
```

Queria pegar somente os 2 maiores da lista no Brasil

Fiz... Oque falta?

```
const filtrados = infos.filter(info => info.local === 'Brasil').slice(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que quando diz *"...Queria pegar somente os 2 maiores da lista no Brasil.."* esteja querendo em sua lista filtrar os elementos cujo o local seja o Brasil e apanhar os dois elemento cujo apresente a maior quantidade.

Analisando o fragmento apresentado na resposta o falta apenas classificar a lista em ordem crescente, o que pode ser feito com o auxilio do método [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), e então apanhar os dois últimos elementos, o que pode ser feito passando um argumento negativo como inicio da fatia para o método [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const infos = [{"nome":"Carlos", "quantidade":"25", "local":"Inglaterra"},{"nome":"Mariana", "quantidade":"15", "local":"Brasil"},{"nome":"Gustavo", "quantidade":30, "local":"França"},{"nome":"Murilo", "quantidade":"60", "local":"Belgica"},{"nome":"Luiz", "quantidade":"10", "local":"Brasil"},{"nome":"Tata", "quantidade":"18", "local":"Brasil"}];

const filtrados = 
   infos
   .filter(info => info.local === 'Brasil')                 //Filtra os elementos cujo o local é Brasil...
   .sort((a,b)=> Number(a.quantidade)-Number(b.quantidade)) //Classifica a lista filtrada em ordem crescente pelo campo quantidade...
   .slice(-2);                                              //Busca uma fatia composta apenas pelos os dois últimos elementos.

console.log(filtrados);
```

Vale destacar que o método `Array.prototype.sort()` possui um parâmetro `funcaoDeComparacao` que quando fornecido, o array será classificado de acordo com o valor de retorno da `funcaoDeComparacao`. Considerando que `a` e `b` são dois elementos sendo comparados.
A `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` sempre deve retornar o mesmo valor dado um par específico de elementos `a` e `b` como argumentos. Se resultados inconsistentes são retornados, então a classificação é indefinida, então:

- Se `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` for menor que `0`, ordena `a` para um índice anterior a `b`.
- Se `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` retornar `0`, deixa `a` e `b` inalterados em relação um ao outro, mas ordenado em relação a todos os outros elementos.
- Se `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` é maior que `0`, ordena `b` para um índice anterior que `a`.